# Does windows currently have a method of giving full access to all folders, services, and processes?

Tags: windows-7, permissions

There are many files, services, and processes which even as an admin I cannot modify, start/stop, or kill that I would like to modify.

Even when the task is ran as an evaluated user, these files, services, and processes still cannot be changed.

How do I gain permanent access to these files, services, and processes?

Some examples of how this can be done:

Log in as TrustedInstaller, or the login agent ("SYSTEM" I think it's called).
re-permissioning all files, services, and processes (preferably not manually).
Disabling, or re-configuring the permissions of the accounts who own the files (TrustedInstaller and SYSTEM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` account is what you're looking for.

You can get a command prompt under this account fairly easily using [SysInternal's PsExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec).

Note that:

- Even as this account, an owner of a file can deny you access to a file or other principal using ACLs.  You can take ownership and change the ACLs though.
- Windows has the notion of exclusive filesystem locks, so this can prevent you from opening some files even as `SYSTEM` if another process has it open.  The `SAM` file is an example (though it's possible to get the in-memory copy through various methods, [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Account_Manager).)